# Odoo v16 not showing new messages

Tags: nginx, odoo, livechat

I got an odoo 16 and messages from chat are not vissible unless i refresh the page, in the pas i have faced the same problem but then i correct the websocket or the port, but this time i have no idea what the problem could be.

Im using cloudflare and the certyficates was installed by certbot.

**This is my nginx config:**

```
upstream odoo {
     server 127.0.0.1:8069;
 }

upstream odoo-im {
     server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}

server {
        root /var/www/html;
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name development.ktc.com.cy;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            # Esta línea viene del upstream
            proxy_pass http://odoo;
            proxy_redirect off;
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
       location /longpolling {

     proxy_connect_timeout 600;

     proxy_send_timeout 600;

     proxy_read_timeout 600;

     send_timeout 600;

     proxy_pass http://odoo-im;

} location /websocket {
            # Esta línea viene del upstream
            proxy_pass http://odoo-im;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            #proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       }
       location /odoo-im {
           # Esta línea viene del upstream
           proxy_pass http://odoo-im;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      }
        gzip_types text/css text/scss text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json applicat>
        gzip on;




    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/development.ktc.com.cy/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/development.ktc.com.cy/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
  

      if ($host = development.ktc.com.cy) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
    
    
            server_name development.ktc.com.cy;
        listen 80;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    
    
    }

**And this is my odoo.conf**
                                                          
    [options]
    ; This is the password that allows database operations:
    admin_passwd = XXXXXXXXXX
    http_port = 8069
    logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
    addons_path=/odoo/odoo-server/addons,/odoo/custom/addons,/opt/KTCBrainPack
    
    limit_memory_hard = 1677721600
    limit_memory_soft = 629145600
    limit_request = 8192
    limit_time_cpu = 600
    limit_time_real = 1200

workers = 9
max_cron_threads = 1
proxy_mode = True
```

I have done this several times, i now i really dont understand whats the problem. I appreciate any help